# Will this code be considered bubble or selection sort?

Tags: java, arrays, bubble-sort, selection-sort

Could you please help identify what sorting method is this?

```java
public static int[] sort(int arr[]) {
    int temp1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j] < arr[i]) {
                temp1 = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp1;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither. It is close to selection sort, but makes unnecessary swaps.

**Bubble sort** makes pair-wise swaps on subsequent elements, until the "lightest" element is at top, like a bubble goes up in fluid.

```
int unorderedLen = arr.length;
do {
  int newUnorderedLen = 0;
  // after a cycle, largest element will be at top
  for (int i = 1; i < unorderedLen; j++) {
    if (arr[i-1] > arr[i]) {
      newUnorderedLen = i;
      swap(arr, i, i-1);
    }
  }
  unorderedLen = newUnorderedLen;
} while (unorderedLen > 0);
```

**Selection sort** searches and *selects* the place where an element should fit and makes a single swap after.

```
// at i. cycle, we select i. least element and place at i.
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
  int minIndex = i;
  // search for least element in the remaining unsorted
  for (int j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {
    if (arr[j] < arr[minIndex]) {
      minIndex = j;
    }
  }
  if (minIndex != i) {
    swap(arr, minIndex, i);
  }
}
```